# Insert image in code (.cs) file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can we insert an image in CS (VS2008) file as an reference to support the complex logic?

The code is quite complex so I want to put the UML image of that code to increase the understanding.

Ram

Comment: Internally image is just sequence of binary data. So read binary data and store it in any file you want. But i am not sure how you want to insert it.

Comment: explain more what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Reniuz - Please check the description now.

Comment: no you can't I think Guganeshan.T posted best answer for you. Code is code, documentation is documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hyperlink in a comment.
Example:

`// See reference image: http://ourserver.com/documentation/images/reference1.jpg`

And it will turn into a working hyperlink that anyone can click while pressing the CTRL key

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to embed an image inside the code editor?
In Visual Studio you can't do that (maybe there exists a 3rd party plugin which i'm not aware of).

All you can do is to embed some ascii art or add the image as separate file to your project and reference it in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can embed image inside the code editor. But the only extension I know it is *Image Insertion* extension for *Visual Studio 2010*.
You can get it from [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/793d16d0-235a-439a-91df-4ce7c721df12).

Comment: Any way I think it's possible only in Visual Studio 2010 because of WPF based code editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can but for that you will need to create a static byte array and manually fill the array from the bytes of the image file like: `static byte[] img = new byte[]{/*all image file bytes*}`

I would suggest you to add the image as a resource to the assembly and then you can read it at runtime and do the required processing.