# Where is the visual studio HTML Designer?

Tags: html, visual-studio, ide

Where is the Visual Studio HTML Designer? I see that there are options for the HTML Designer but I can't open it.
[image: There is a HTML Designer options node!]

So I just want to ask why I can't find the designer and how do I open it. When I create an HTML file it just goes to the HTML code.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The default HTML editor (for static HTML) doesn't have a design view. To set the default editor to the Web forms editor which does have a design view,

1. Right click any HTML file in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and click on `Open with`
2. Select the `HTML (web forms) editor`
3. Click on `Set as default`
4. Click on the `OK` button

Once you have done that, all you need to do is click on `design` or `split` view as shown below:

[image: Screenshot showing the location of said options]

Comment: Help this did not work for me, I mean I followed the steps but I don't get the options at the bottom for Design or Split.  There is only one - Source!

Comment: You also have to do it in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, not the file explorer (Windows). For one of my customers we had to create a blank project, create a blank HTML file and then we could right click it to see the correct open with menu

Comment: I just made the web forms editor Default but if I try to open existing CSHTML or HTML pages in my solution after doing this, the pages are all blank and there's still no Design | Split | Source tabs at the bottom. This also happens if I use Add to add a html or cshtml file to my project. If I just use New -> File menu to create an HTML file, things are fine with the Design | Spliut | Source tabs showing at the bottom. What is this IDE insanity?

Comment: @DarrenEvans cshtml files are not compatible with the editor (simply renaming them to html isn't going to change that).

Comment: Keep in mind, this doesn't work with files added As Link.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 appears to be ignoring this. It only shows "Source".

Comment: @NickeManarin Works for me... try reinstalling VS

Comment: took some steps for it to work, had to do this step in addition to the one mentioned by @user5470600, had to change the default view to split. it didn't work at first. closing the HTML then opening it again did the trick

Comment: Seems to work in VS 2022. Is there a way to have the split vertical instead of horizontal?

Answer (score 37):

Another way of setting the default to the HTML web forms editor is:

1. At the top menu in Visual Studio go to `File` > `New` > `File`
2. Select `HTML Page`
3. In the lower right corner of the New File dialog on the `Open` button there is a down arrow
4. Click it and you should see an option `Open With`
5. Select `HTML (Web Forms) Editor`
6. Click `Set as Default`
7. Press `OK`

[image: Screenshot showing how to get to the "Open With" dialog box when creating a new file.]

Comment: Don't get a "Open With" for a new file (VS 2015) but you can create it, then in the Solution Explorer window, you can right click and choose `Open With...` then `HTML (Web Forms) Editor`as before.

Comment: @kjhf "Open With" is there in the new `VS2015` version as well. It has moved slightly below. You will see it at the bottom of the `File Dialog`

Comment: @cflyer Thank you for sharing your solution - specially describing it step by step along with a sceenshot. It helped me.

Answer (score 13):

Go to [Tools, Options], section "Web Forms Designer" and enable the option "Enable Web Forms Designer". That should give you the Design and Split option again.

Comment: For me this option was already enabled but that didn't make the other editing views available.

Comment: Thanks -- this is also where the "Split Views Vertically" option is.   Requires a restart to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

The solution of creating a new HTML file with HTML (Web Forms) Designer worked for that file but not for other, individual HTML files that I wanted to edit.

I did find the Open With option in the Open File dialogue and was able to select the HTML (Web Forms) Editor there. Having clicked the "Set as Default" option in that window, VS then remembered to use that editor when I opened other HTML files.