# .aspx not rendering properly in Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hi I am using visual studio 2015 in Windows 7 . Have added an "ASP.NET Web Application" in my solution . when I am trying to render design and split view of aspx page it's not rendering. 
Have seen this problem can be solved by Changing target version in web project (not target framework), I am not sure where to get the target version to change it ..Any help ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it render properly in Chrome or FireFox if so then what about checking the compatibility mode in InternetExplorer if this is where it's rendering improperly..

Comment: based on the screen shot you just provided change the dropdown of the target version and select the .net framework version that you want to target for example `4.0`

Comment: @MethodMan ..aspx design view is not working in Visual Studio . Sorry for the confusion..It's not related to browser

Comment: what do you mean when you say not working .. you mean you are not seeing a menu item to view designer..? if so read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654960/where-is-the-visual-studio-html-designer

Comment: @MethodMan I have already tried above option , in my case all 3 options are showing , design , split and source , but when I click design , it's not loading.Attached a screenshot

Comment: what's the master page look like..

Comment: Master page is the default one comes with vs2015. I haven't touched it. even without master page faced the same issue

Comment: try looking for a update / SP for visual studio 2015 I am all out of ideas

Comment: Thanks man, will update and let you know if it works for me

Comment: I haven't use **Design** view for years, because it is not really useful in web programming. I'm just saying.