# Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 Design View not showing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I click on Design nothing happens still showing code only.[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Your first screen shot is of a html page which [doesn't have a designer by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654960/where-is-the-visual-studio-html-designer)

Comment: It' not only with html bro also with asp.When I click nothing happens.
I already changed throgh option

Comment: no fix for this :(