# Visual Studio 2017 - Design View/Split view

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, designing an HTML page with a linked JavaScript page for functionality. Up until today, beneath my main pane where my code is, there was a bar that had 3 options, Design, Split and Source. I'm not sure why or how the bar has vanished, but it has and I'm not sure what it is called or how to display it again. I have tried Microsoft support to no avail, I've googled and not been successful, and of course tried a variety of things within Visual Studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655106/5758637 does this work for you?

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

May be useful for some one coming later  [image]

Go to tools-->Option-->Web Forms Designer  , Select Split View Vertically option. Restart the  Visual Studio