# Simple browser in Visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual studio 2022:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.7.2
```

and can remember that in older versions you could open a "Browser window" to view web pages within the IDE (I find that really useful when I'm studying some code from blog posts and presentations and don't want to switch back and forth between my browser and my IDE).

VsCode has the "Simple browser" command but Visual studio had this feature many years ago. Is it gone now? Can I somehow enable it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654960/where-is-the-visual-studio-html-designer

Comment: @HansPassant But I don't want an HTML designer/editor, just the integrated browser. I see there's [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=odalet.webbrowserforvs2022) to bring it back so I guess the feature is removed from visual studio